# Multi language sites

Tags: permissions, user-profile, active-directory, language

We are about to create a multi lingual portal for a customer that has offices in many countries. We will have site collections with different language packs. All our users will have access to the whole portal.

Any guidance/best practice tips on how to set up our portal with regards to permissions and groups in SharePoint and AD ?

Comment: Too bad nobody knows!

Comment: Is it on-prem or Office 365?

Comment: on-prem. This is a very old post though, almost 6 months now. We ended up creating site collections with different language pack for each country. All users have (read) access to the portal. We implemented redirect logic so that the users are redirected to site collection of their country when the log on the portal.

Comment: Did you try following this reference? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262055.aspx