# How to Build a Multi-Language Site?

Tags: office-365, site, variations, language, multilingual

We are using Office-365 and need to set up a multi-language sharepoint site.  How do we do this?

- [I see a question here about permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126641/multi-language-sites).
- [And I have a question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145344/how-to-test-languages-in-enterprise-wiki) about how to test multi-languages in an Enterprise Wiki site.

But nobody has answered any of those questions yet.  So I am asking this one which is not so limited in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-lingual sites can be implemented in Office 365 but it depends if you want to translate content + labels or labels-only.

- If you're interested in translating content + labels between different
  languages then I suggest variations is not a bad option at all. The
  only down-side is that you get subsites created for different
  languages instead of site collections:
  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-multi-language-website-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6
- Office 365 also provides support in labels-only translation, which means labels can be automatically translated when UI language is changed in the
  SharePoint site. Here's quick guide on how to enable it and what artifacts are supported [with additional guidance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/03/20/office365-multilingual-content-types-site-columns-and-site-other-elements.aspx)

  Site Title

  Site Description

  List Title

  List Description

  Content Type Name

  Content Type Description

  Site column Title

  Site column Description

Comment: Have you used either method?  What do you prefer?

Comment: Yes, even though variations have improved a lot since previous versions but I wouldn't recommend unless you requirements are driven by multi-lingual sites with strong focus on content translations. You can be better off building providing multi-lingual with labels only and let users to managed content translations by themselves. Moreover, labels translation is simply easy to set up and manage so I would definitely weigh this option.

Comment: Okay, so I've experimented some with workflowed variations.  Now I want to try using labels.

Comment: So, to use labels I have to use label-enabled content types? I am reading the link you posted, but am confused.

Comment: I'm not understanding labels yet.  So I can change the basic interface language, but custom links and custom content are still in the original language.  I'm missing something.  As far as I understand, "labels" only refers to the built-in interface links.

Comment: Labels can be of two types. One that SharePoint provides you out of the box like labels on Site Settings, Site collection administration, Ribbon etc. Second is the custom ones like site title, site description, list names, site columns, content types which has to be localized using custom development. SharePoint supports localization on both when UI language is changed.